# How to delete a config after comparing and getting the difference in an Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I am struggling to delete a DHCP config after comparing 2 configs using the Ansible difference feature. I have registered the error output in a variable at the end for better understanding. I am calling the first `item` from a list in a yml file then the second item is the difference between the two configs which needs to be deleted.

My playbook tasks:

```
    - name: Verify the Added DHCP Config on NXOS Devices
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - show running-config dhcp | include Vlan|Ethernet|address
      register: post_output

    - name: View Data from the show run dhcp command
      debug:
        var: post_output.stdout_lines

    - name: Capture the Existing DHCP Server Config
      set_fact:
        existing_dhcp_config: "{{ post_output['stdout'][0] | regex_findall('interface \\S+|ip dhcp relay address \\S+') }}"

    - name: View the existing DHCP Server IP(s)
      debug:
        var: existing_dhcp_config

    - name: Desired DHCP Server Config Based on Site Standards
      set_fact:
        desired_dhcp_config: "{{ lookup('file', './DHCP-Config/{{ inventory_hostname }}-dhcp.cfg') | regex_findall('interface \\S+|ip dhcp relay address \\S+') }}"
    
    - name: View Desired DHCP Server Config
      debug:
        var: desired_dhcp_config

    - name: Compare Existing and Desired Configs to Remove Stale Config
      set_fact:
        dhcp_config_to_remove: "{{ existing_dhcp_config | difference(desired_dhcp_config) }}"

    - name: View the Difference Against Existing and Desired DHCP Configs
      debug:
        var: dhcp_config_to_remove

    - name: Delete Non-Site Standards DHCP Config
      nxos_config:
        parents: interface {{ item }}
        commands: no {{ item }}
        diff_against: running
        save_when: modified
      loop:
        - "{{ interfaces }}"
        - "{{ dhcp_config_to_remove }}"
      register: var
      ignore_errors: yes

    - debug:
        var: var
```

Playbook run output:

```
=========================
Running DHCP/IP Helper Add Playbook
=========================
:
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [Verify the Added DHCP Config on NXOS Devices] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View Data from the show run dhcp command] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "post_output.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "interface Vlan1",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 ",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98 ",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99 ",
            "interface Ethernet1/49",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 ",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98 ",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99 ",
            "interface Ethernet1/50",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 ",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98 ",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [Capture the Existing DHCP Server Config] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View the existing DHCP Server IP(s)] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "existing_dhcp_config": [
        "interface Vlan1",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99",
        "interface Ethernet1/49",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99",
        "interface Ethernet1/50",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99"
    ]
}

TASK [Desired DHCP Server Config Based on Site Standards] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View Desired DHCP Server Config] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "desired_dhcp_config": [
        "interface Vlan1",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "interface Ethernet1/49",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "interface Ethernet1/50",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2"
    ]
}

TASK [Compare Existing and Desired Configs to Remove Stale Config] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View the Difference Against Existing and Desired DHCP Configs] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "dhcp_config_to_remove": [
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99"
    ]
}

TASK [Delete Non-Site Standards DHCP Config] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [nxos-1] (item=['Vlan1', 'Ethernet1/49 - 50']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": ["Vlan1", "Ethernet1/49 - 50"], "msg": "interface ['Vlan1'\r\r\n                               ^\r\nInvalid interface format at '^' marker.\r\n\rnxos-1(config)# "}
failed: [nxos-1] (item=['ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98', 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": ["ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98", "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99"], "msg": "interface ['ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98'\r\r\n                               ^\r\nInvalid interface format at '^' marker.\r\n\rnxos-1(config)# "}
...ignoring

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "var": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "after": null,
                        "auth_pass": null,
                        "authorize": null,
                        "backup": false,
                        "backup_options": null,
                        "before": null,
                        "commands": "no ['Vlan1', 'Ethernet1/49 - 50']",
                        "defaults": false,
                        "diff_against": "running",
                        "diff_ignore_lines": null,
                        "host": null,
                        "intended_config": null,
                        "lines": [
                            "no ['Vlan1'",
                            " 'Ethernet1/49 - 50']"
                        ],
                        "match": "line",
                        "parents": [
                            "interface ['Vlan1'",
                            " 'Ethernet1/49 - 50']"
                        ],
                        "password": null,
                        "port": null,
                        "provider": null,
                        "replace": "line",
                        "replace_src": null,
                        "running_config": null,
                        "save_when": "modified",
                        "src": null,
                        "ssh_keyfile": null,
                        "timeout": null,
                        "transport": null,
                        "use_ssl": null,
                        "username": null,
                        "validate_certs": null
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    "Vlan1",
                    "Ethernet1/49 - 50"
                ],
                "msg": "interface ['Vlan1'\r\r\n                               ^\r\nInvalid interface format at '^' marker.\r\n\rnxos-1(config)# "
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "after": null,
                        "auth_pass": null,
                        "authorize": null,
                        "backup": false,
                        "backup_options": null,
                        "before": null,
                        "commands": "no ['ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98', 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99']",
                        "defaults": false,
                        "diff_against": "running",
                        "diff_ignore_lines": null,
                        "host": null,
                        "intended_config": null,
                        "lines": [
                            "no ['ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98'",
                            " 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99']"
                        ],
                        "match": "line",
                        "parents": [
                            "interface ['ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98'",
                            " 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99']"
                        ],
                        "password": null,
                        "port": null,
                        "provider": null,
                        "replace": "line",
                        "replace_src": null,
                        "running_config": null,
                        "save_when": "modified",
                        "src": null,
                        "ssh_keyfile": null,
                        "timeout": null,
                        "transport": null,
                        "use_ssl": null,
                        "username": null,
                        "validate_certs": null
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
                    "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99"
                ],
                "msg": "interface ['ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98'\r\r\n                               ^\r\nInvalid interface format at '^' marker.\r\n\rnxos-1(config)# "
            }
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
nxos-1                : ok=11   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

group_vars/nxos.yml:

```
---

interfaces: ["Vlan1", "Ethernet1/49 - 50"]
```

Comment: I have posted the answer, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
TASK [Delete Non-Site Standards DHCP Config] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [nxos-1] => (item=['Vlan1', 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98'])
changed: [nxos-1] => (item=['Vlan1', 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99'])
changed: [nxos-1] => (item=['Ethernet1/49 - 50', 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98'])
changed: [nxos-1] => (item=['Ethernet1/49 - 50', 'ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99'])

TASK [Verify the Final DHCP Config on NXOS Devices] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View Data from the show run dhcp command] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "final_output.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "interface Vlan1",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 ",
            "interface Ethernet1/49",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 ",
            "interface Ethernet1/50",
            "  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2"
        ]
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
nxos-1                : ok=17   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```